# ODataSetName for Custom Entity in retrieving entity using REST Endpoint

Tags: javascript, ajax, dynamics-crm-2011, odata

In my restendpoint.js, I have the retrieveRecord function as defined [here](http://dynamics2011.blogspot.com/2012/03/crm-2011-and-odata-retrieve-example.html)

I have a function which should run on change of the Programme (a lookup field) on the Application entity. It should basically retrieve the attributes of Programme record.

I am a little confused about what should be the oDataSetName?

The Display Name of my entity is Programme
The name of entity is ntt_programme

I have tried ProgrammeSet and ntt_ProgrammeSet but to no success. The ajax call results in the failure callback method, i.e, in my case I get the alert `In ProgrammeErrorCallBack`

1. Why is it resulting in failure call back method?
2. What should be the oDataSetName and where exactly in CRM is this stored - is it always EntityName followed by Set?

I am a little lost here as I am completely new to JS / AJAX / REST / JSON!

---

```
ProgrammeOnChange: function () {
    var programmeLookup = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_programmeid").getValue();
    if (programmeLookup != null && programmeLookup[0] && programmeLookup[0].name != null) {
        var programmeId = programmeLookup[0].id;
        alert(programmeId);
        var oDataSetName = "ProgrammeSet";
        CRM2011Common.Functions.retrieveRecord(programmeId, oDataSetName, CRM2011.Application.ProgrammeSuccessCallBack, CRM2011.Application.ProgrammeErrorCallBack);
    }
},

ProgrammeSuccessCallBack: function (result) {
    alert("In ProgrammeSuccessCallBack");
    var programme = result;
    alert(programme.new_name);
},

ProgrammeErrorCallBack: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("In ProgrammeErrorCallBack");
    alert('Error retrieving Programme: ' + textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a capitalization issue.  It should be `ntt_programmeSet`, or something equal to that, but with different casing.

I always recommend using [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to test REST oData calls first.  It'll keep you from having any errors due to casing issues.  You can create a new odata connection to the CRM SDK endpoint, and then write a linq statement to pull back the information. If you click on the Lambda symbol, it will give you the odata URL. As long as your javascript generates the exact url, you should be good.

Comment: Thanks for advise about the use of LinqPad to test REST oData calls. Will get back to you regarding the capitalization problem in a little while. And, it works like a charm!